# jQuery.post outputting dropdown list

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have created a dropdown list, which is working well in separate page:
[image: normal]

however, when I use `jQuery.post()` to output it in a table in a PP page, the contents run out from the dropdown list:
[image: abnormal]

The jQuery that I am using us like this:

```
<script>
function showestate(){
$.post('admin/page/ur/showestate.php',{ 
zid: document.getElementById('zone').value

},
function(output){
$('#showestate').html(output);
}); 
}
showestate();
</script>

<div id='showestate'>
    </div>
```

please help! Thanks!

the dropdown list is like this:

```
<?php
include "../../db.php";
session_start();

?>
<select name="estate" id="estate" />
<?php
$sql_sel_estate = "select * from [estate]";
$result_sel_estate = mssql_query($sql_sel_estate, $conn);
while ($record_sel_estate = mssql_fetch_array($result_sel_estate))
{
$estateid = $record_sel_estate['estateid'];
$estatename = $record_sel_estate['estatename'];
$estatenameen = $record_sel_estate['estatenameen'];
$estatezoneid = $record_sel_estate['estatezoneid'];
$estatecode = $record_sel_estate['estatecode'];

?>

<option value="<?=$estateid?>">
<?=$estatenameen?><br>
</option>
<?php
}
?>
</select>
```

Comment: please provide more information about this, php code ...

Comment: Please show what the response is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to check/alert  what comes back in `output`

It should contain

```
<option>option 1</option>
<option>option 2</option>
<option>option 3</option>
```

i.e. only the options. no other html. Nothing else.

also create a `<select>` element with id `showestate`. You can give any other id to div
as you are adding the html to `showestate`